# ASP.Net Email SmtpException Issue

Tags: asp.net, email

When I try to sendmail using asp.net I get the following error.

> Error Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires
>   a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
>   response was: Relaying not  allowed

I have used the right credentials (through which we could access web mail)

**I have configured the mail using Google Labs. Does this affect anyway?**

```
MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("info@thewebsite.com", "thewebsite.com");
mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ToAddress));
mailMsg.Subject = Subject;
mailMsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");



System.Net.Mail.AlternateView plainView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BodyText, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty), null, "text/plain");
System.Net.Mail.AlternateView htmlView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(BodyText, null, "text/html");

mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
mailMsg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


// Smtp configuration
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

string smtphost = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtphost"].ToString();
int smtpport = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpport"].ToString());


smtp.Host = smtphost; 
smtp.Port = smtpport;  


smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@thewebsite.com", "pwd1234");
```

Comment: ANSWER: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail/32336#32336    It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that u must set the `smtp.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: Now the issue becomes:  Error Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Server does not support secure connections.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Comment: Great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail/32336#32336  worked. Thanks a lot!